Finding duration of given payment
Question :A corporation bond with annual coupon rate 7,5% will mature at 30 june 2025.Find duration of the bond on 31 december 2023 given that the annual interest rate is 5,5%.Assume the par value is 1.
Heres my attempt:Let P denote the current bond price
$P= \frac{0,075}{1,055}+\frac{1}{1,055^{1,5}} $
and  $C=\frac{1*0,075}{1,055}+\frac{1,5*1}{1,055^{1,5}} $
Hence by macaulay duration formula we get $Duration=\frac{C}{P}=1,464$
However it does not appear on the option. So is there any mistake on my attempt?

If I am reading correctly, your price for the $18$ month bond is $0.99391921$, right?  But that's less that par...why would you sell a bond with a coupon higher than the risk free rate below par?

On brief inspection, it appears that you have neglected the stub coupon.  You are owed $3.75%$ as of June $2024$.

@lulu do you meant at june 2025? because on my attempt i have covered it by using 1 year annual coupon.However  the result is still the same which is about 1,465.

Yes, you include the full coupon paid at the end,  but this bond pays an annual coupon, so there is a coupon due in June $2024$. Of course, you are buying the bond as of Dec $2023$ so you only get half of it.
